# Sorting a Paginated Mongoid Collection in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, kaminari

I am using a pagination gem (kaminari) in my Rails app and having a hard time sorting a collection of Mongo documents.

First I structure my query, which is to retrieve one page worth of all the newest comments for a user:

```
comments = user.comments.desc(:created_at).page(params[:page])
```

By default this will give me 25 records. I then want to render each comment, but now reverse the order so that the newest comment will be on the bottom:

```
comments.asc(:created_at).each do |comment|
  - render the comment
```

However, by calling asc on my comments variable, it's just redefining the query and giving me the oldest comments for that user, not the newest comments.

How can I retrieve the collection and sort that object, rather than simply changing the scope of my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call to_a on a mongoid query, it will execute the query at that point.

```
comments = user.comments.desc(:created_at).page(params[:page])
comments.to_a.reverse.each do |comment|
  - render the comment
```

So we're calling comments to an array, and then reversing the array

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!  Not sure how obvious this was, but I'm new. Appreciate your help.